# Apply binary search to combine two sorted sub arrays using recursive merge sort in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Apply binary search to combine two sorted sub arrays using recursive merge sort :

```
void combine(int a[],int low,int mid,int high)
{
int temp[50],i,j,k;
i=low;
j=mid+1;
k=0;
int m=(low+mid)/2;
while(i<=mid&&j<=high)
{
    if(a[m]<a[j])
    {
        for(i=low;i<=m;i++)
        {
            temp[k]=a[i];
            k++;
        }
        low=mid+1;
        j++;
        m=(low+mid)/2;
    }
    else
    {
            high=m-1;
            m=(low+mid)/2;
}
```

Above Function is to perform binary search and merge to sorted sub arrays
Here sub arrays are:
 1) *a[low]to a[mid]*
 2) *a[mid+1] to a[high]*

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I am trying to apply binary search on two sorted arrays (sorted using merge sort). Binary search has to be applied such that it combines to sorted arrays.Like in general merge sort we apply linear search to merge elements. Instead of linear search I have to use Binary search.

Comment: When you do binary search, you search for something ? What are you searching for ? As for merging two sorted arrays one doesn't need to do binary search.

Comment: In binary search, I would be searching for correct place for a[mid+1]to a[high] elements in array a[low]to a[mid]

Comment: One doesn't need binary search to merge two sorted arrays. Why do you want to apply it?

Comment: IF you look at merge sort, you will see that you do not need to search for elements to merge two sorted arrays, as the other have noted. Further, you don't have to reinvent the wheel and can use `std::merge`. And it would be nice to add a question to your post.

Comment: You would need binary search when you trying to merge two arrays using more than one thread. Perhaps that is the question, otherwise as noted above binary search is not needed.